# Glyphicon calendar is not open

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I try to use bootstrap datetimepicker with the glyphicon calendar. But if I click the picker, nothing happens.

Even the calendar doesn't open. I added the following *.js* and *.css* files in my *.jsp* page:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/jquery-ui.css"  />
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/1.9.2.jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Please help me figure out how to use the bootstrap datetimepicker v4 version. Are any other *.js* and *.css* files  required? The datetimepicker is displayed as in the image:

[image]

That's where if I click the picker, the calendar does not open.

Answer (score 0):

after

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

write

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
</script>
```

in `HTML` use the below code

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
<input type='text' class="form-control" />
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
</div>
```